# how to find out in SFMC all subscribers comprises of which country - like list demographic report?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, reporting, sql, subscriber

I am looking to to find out how many contacts in all subscribers are from europe country (for GDPR). is there any report that shows me list demographics (countries)?

if no out of the box report then any way to extract users from europe based on the email address (domain)? considering there is NO dedicated attribute where country value is saved. All we got is the email address.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, this isn't possible, certainly not in a post-hoc analysis.

You have "domain" in _subscribers data view and can easily isolate everything behind the `.` using SQL, giving you the top-level domains country.

```
/* remove everything left of the . */
SELECT Replace(domain,
LEFT(EmailAddress,(PATINDEX('%.%',EmailAddress) - 1)),
'') 
FROM _Subscribers
```

Nice, but that is totally pointless and if you mention GDPR, then I don't think a "ballpark  / rule of thumb solution" like this is something that anyone will care about.

Case in point: I am in Europe and my email account is on a .com domain. While more unlikely the other way round, nothing also stops US citizens from getting an account at a French provider etc.

You simply cannot infer country of origin from email addresses or domains in a valid way.

What these tracing solutions on the web usually rely upon is an IP address (which can also be a proxy...) collected at some point, in case of an emailing system like SFMC, likely registration. Marketing cloud out of the box does not store IP addresses in any of the system tables you can access, or stop you from registering / importing email addresses without an IP address listed.

Technically, all addresses could come from other systems, or excel sheets found on the street. So maybe there isn't even a registration gateway where you could read out IPs.  Not saying that's a smart approach, but plausible.

as for reading out IPs, SSJS can be easily used for this.
https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/10/25/retrieve-client-ip-address-and-geolocation-in-cloudpages/

Which doesn't help you for email addresses already in your system, doesn't rule out that proxies are used to mask real locations, and, if implemented, raises the next GDPR question, as in: is it ok to collect and store this, and for how long? Which is something your resident legal counsel will have to answer.